# HTTP not redirecting to HTTPS on IIS 10

Tags: iis, https, http-redirect, iis-10

I am super new at this and got thrown into running a site with no experience so I apologize for the stupid question. I installed an SSL certificate for our site example.example.com (wildcard certificate from digicert for the domain) and the site https://example.example.com works. But when I just type in the url example.example.com the browser loads for a while and gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I've spent a ton of time on google and trying various combinations of the URL rewrite rules on stack overflow and other websites but nothing works. This is how it's set up currently in web.config

```
<rule name="Redirect http to https" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

I don't think it's a rule issue because they seem pretty simple but like I said, I am very new to this

This is the only site on this server and the bindings are below

[image: bindings]

Thanks

Comment: How many sites are there on your IIS and what are the site bindings? You should make that very clear by editing your question.

Comment: Next, use a privacy tab in your browser to test. Otherwise, your previous failed attempts might be cached and lead to weird issues.

Comment: I tried iisreset and used a private window, same thing happens unfortunately

Comment: Enable FRT and set status code to 200-999, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-php-with-failed-request-tracing and then you should be able to figure out if 301 responses were generated by the rewrite rule as expected. "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" might be another issue but FRT again should provide you enough hints.

Comment: I enabled FRT but it's not logging anything for the http site. I'm pretty sure I set it up right because I tried a non existent subdomain of the https site and it was logged correctly

Comment: Then time to involve your network administrators. They can tell where the requests went and why not landed on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thank you- I just tried updating the rule to this and the same thing happens

Answer (score -1):

When using the Chrome browser and trying to access a website, an err_empty_response (Error Empty Response) message may appear. This means that data is not being sent/transmitted. Please try the following methods to resolve this issue:

1. Clear your browser's cache, cookies and temporary files.
2. It can also cause problems if you have extensions enabled on your Chrome browser. You need to try disabling extensions to see if that fixes the problem. Go to chrome://extensions in your Chrome browser.
3. Try using another browser to see if the same problem occurs.